# Php - didn't update row in mysql by using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to update a row in PHP by using PDO... but couldn't do that, & not giving an error too...

my SQL update function in php:
// PDO Function To Handle Prepared Statements (FOR ALL QUERY)

```
function sql($DBH, $query, $params, $return) {
        try {
            // Prepare statement
            $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
            // Execute statement
            $STH->execute($params);
            // Decide whether to return the rows themselves, or just count the rows
            if ($return == "rows") {
                return $STH->fetchAll();
            }
            elseif ($return == "count") {
                return $STH->rowCount();
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) { 
            file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND); # Errors Log File
        }
    }
```

my PDO SQL code for the update:

```
sql($DBH, "UPDATE tbl_causes SET title=?,para1=?,bullets=?,img=? WHERE id = ?", array($title, $para1, $bullets, $img, $id), "rows");
```

Comment: it works when I insert the row but didn't work in update

Comment: Wait, I think I see the issue now. Where are you returning the result to? `return $STH->fetchAll();` is returning it to something. So your executiong should be something like `$result = sql($DBH, "UPDATE ... );`. Do `print_r($result);` and see what it contains.

Comment: didn't show anything...

Comment: Add these 3 lines to the top of your PHP code and try again: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Right underneath `<?php`

Comment: sql function in my function.php & calling this function is in update.php... sorry where i put this code in function.php or update.php

Comment: It's best to put it in both.